# How can i fix Linux Mint 19.1's GNOME terminal not TAB-autocompleting file names in apt?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, apt, autocomplete, gnome-terminal

I have a .deb package downloaded that i want to install using apt. 
When i wanted to TAB-autocomplete the following command nothing happened.

```
$ sudo apt install ./pa[TAB]
```

However, when i tried `$ ./pa[TAB]` it did fill in the file name.
In both cases the package had rwxrwxr-x permissions.

I know that Ubuntu 18.10's terminal is filling is filenames in the first command. Is it possible to have the same function in Mint?

I'm using bash and GNOME Terminal 3.28.1

Comment: I'm installing a locally downloaded .deb file. I have tried it without `./` but apt tried to install a remote package.

Comment: I was able to install locally downloaded packages using apt, 'google-chrome-stable' for instance. I remember getting an error about the package being referenced but not available when I tried installing it without `./`. apt downloaded dependencies and used local .deb the path to the file was listed in the Get: section of the log.

Comment: `updatedb` doesn't work in my case. I've got a complete list of remote packages (`sudo apt install pa[tab]`) after running it, but `sudo apt install ./pa[tab]` is not changed.